# Handling Receive Data and Connection closure signal in epoll_wait

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

If the client sends data and invokes `close()`, and the server uses `epoll_wait()` after a long time, causing the triggering of these two events (data arrival and connection closure) within the same `epoll_wait()`, what will be the effect when I use `recv()` to read data in this situation?

I know that `recv()`returns 0 when the connection is closed and returns the number read when data comes, but what does it return in this case?

Comment: IMO: The data was received by the system; it should still be available to `recv()` even if the connection were also closed (so a second `recv()` should return 0 if all the data was read by the first).  I've not verified that empirically, but I would be surprised to find that it was not what happened.  OTOH, I often get surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recv()` returns 0 when there is no more data to be received. Therefore, so long as there is data that could be received, it should not return 0.

So, if the client does `send()` followed by `close()`, assuming the `send()` was sending a non-zero amount of data, then the TCP state will indicate there was some amount of data delivered followed by `FIN`.

Even if the network delivered the `FIN` out of order, the TCP sequence numbers will indicate that the `FIN` is behind some amount of data, and TCP will wait for the arrival of that data. The client TCP state machine will retransmit if it does not see an acknowledgement of receipt from the server.

These are the reliable and in-order data delivery guarantees of the stream provided by TCP. So, the `recv()` call on the server will not return 0 until after some other `recv()` call consumes the data ahead of the `FIN`.